# VB.Net Currency Converter - Is there an easier way?

Tags: vb.net

Just picked programming up as a hobby, and am very bad. I am trying to build a basic currency converter from the book I have.

My question: Is there is a better way than taking the user input (lets say 5 dollars), convert the text string to a double, multiply by the rate, and then convert it back to a string in order to display it in the other textbox? I mainly ask because the textbook hasn't said how to convert double to string yet, and I found it online but I feel like I'm missing something.

Thanks

Comment: That's about as easy as it gets.  Would you rather ask how to convert a double to a string?  If it seems hard, show us the code you're using.  You might be doing something a bit overkill.

Comment: "the textbook hasn't said how to convert double to string yet" -- `Dim d As Double = 123.456 Dim s As String = d.ToString()`

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, and the code. It's working now. I was mainly confused because my textbook finishes the example problem with txtCurrencyOutput.Text = CurrencyVar and CurrencyVar is a double. Not sure how they pulled that off, when I tried I got an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you're working with money, use the `Decimal` type. It works just like Double in every way, except that `Double` is not 100% accurate for certain arithmetic operations. Decimal is a bit slower, but it's *accurate*, and when you're working with money, the accuracy is almost always more important.

> the textbook hasn't said how to convert double to string yet

That's easy:

```
'The "D" at the end is a special code that means it's a Decimal literal value
Dim d As Decimal = 12345.67D 
Dim s As String = d.ToString()
```

Going the other direction isn't much harder:

```
Dim d2 As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(s)
```

Comment: `when you're working with money, the accuracy is almost always more important.`, when would this not be true? I would wait minutes for a calculation to be processed if it meant I got paid the right amount versus getting paid less. :-) Just curious as to anyone working with money would not favor accuracy over all else.